Lingui Macro does not export "Trans" issue
I am using lingui to translate a React application. I followed the tutorial at their documentation but I got this error:
The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@lingui_macro.js?t=1713353117649&v=fd6e7e81' does not provide an export named 'Trans'

Here is lingui.config.ts content:
/** @type {import('@lingui/conf').LinguiConfig} */
// import { formatter } from "@lingui/format-json";

module.exports = {
  locales: ["en", "cs", "fr", "ar"],
  sourceLocale: "en",
  catalogs: [
    {
      path: "<rootDir>/src/locales/{locale}/messages",
      include: ["<rootDir>/src"],
    },
  ],
  // format: formatter({ style: "minimal" }),
};

and here is the App.tsx content:
import "./App.css";

import { i18n } from "@lingui/core";
import { I18nProvider } from "@lingui/react";
import { messages } from "./locales/en/messages";
import { Test } from "./Test";

i18n.load("en", messages);
i18n.activate("en");

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Test />
      </I18nProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Finally, here is the content of Test component:
import { FC } from "react";
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";

export const Test: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <Trans>Hello World</Trans>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

How to solve this rather than using "Trans" from "@lingui/react"?

Most likely, you need to set up the Vite plugin as well - https://lingui.dev/tutorials/setup-vite

Yup the documentation helped specially the Swc section. But yet it does not work on a 2 workspaces project. Do you know any source to check or learn about it?
